# Flutter: localization not working due to context being null. how to correctly pass it through stateless to stateful?

Tags: flutter, stateless, stateful

I have this stateless widget called `myPage.dart`. which contains a `Stack` of `Texts` and `Stateful List View Builder`.

here is the code (I commented out the 2nd group of `Text` and `Stateful List View Builder` for now:

```
Widget content(BuildContext context) =>
    Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          sameDayText(context),
          SameDayWorkManagement(context),
//            nextDayText(),
//            nextDay.NextDayWorkManagement(),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The `sameDayText` is no problem. probably because the class for that is inside the `myPage.dart` but I can't seem to pass the context to `sameDayWorkManagement.dart` which is a stateful widget that contains a `listview builder`. keep in mind that everything worked in the past. its just that when I tried to add localization now, It seems that the context is null for some reason in the `sameDayWorkManagement`. Localization requires context. and I keep getting error on snippet of codes in the sameDayWorkManagement that localizes text. and again because of the context being null:

here is the sample code of the context being null in the `sameDayWorkManagement.dart`

```
Localization.of(widget.buildContext).getTranslatedValue('wakeup')
```

and here is the script for the `sameDayWorkManagement.dart`

```
class SameDayWorkManagement extends StatefulWidget {
  BuildContext buildContext;
  SameDayWorkManagement(buildContext);
  @override
  _SameDayWorkManagementState createState() => _SameDayWorkManagementState();
}


class _SameDayWorkManagementState extends State<SameDayWorkManagement>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
//      backgroundColor: Color(app_background_color_blue),
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) => SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: new StoreConnector<AppState, MainPageViewModel>(
              converter: (store) => MainPageViewModel.fromStore(store),
              builder: ( _, viewModel) => content(viewModel, constraints),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState () {
    super.initState();
    if(widget.buildContext != null) {
      print("is true");
    } else {
      print("is not true");
    }
  }
```

In initState the result is `is not true`

to be more precise. here is the image of myPage that does not have Localization and instead uses static Japanese Text
[image]

The first dot and Japanese Text with a telephone icon in the right is the `sameDayText` widget. the card below it is the `sameDayWorkManagement` its a list view and its scrollable.
and then the rest bellow are those that I commented out ( for now) called `next day`

Comment: There is no need for you to pass BuildContext as a parameter to stateful widget, because all stateful widgets have their own BuildContexts. Could you please describe what is your goal?

Comment: my goal is for the context in the stateful widget(sameDayWorkManagement) to not be null so that Localization will be working.

Comment: also. the reason why I tried passing context is because it didn't work as is. meaning it gave me an error.

Comment: You can access build context of StatefulWidget by typing `widget.context`. You don't need to pass it in argument

Comment: there is no `widget.context` so I went back to just `context` and here is the error i keep getting `The method 'getTranslatedValue' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getTranslatedValue("wakeup")`

Comment: so all in all that error is my only issue. please help

Comment: In State class you can use `widget.context` to get the context. However it is not yet available in `initState`. You need to access it later. It should work in `build` method.

Answer (score 0):

I created a really ugly work around, so I'm still hoping this would be fixed. my work around is I created a map of all the necessary translated text in myPage using the localization which again is working in there. and pass that map to the sameDayWorkManagement as a parameter. and use that map to populate my needed text. yes it is very ugly. but for now it is working.